# Make em units relative to an ancestor that is not the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to make em units relative to say an outer paragraph element instead of it's immediate parent? Override the cascade?

In the example below, the word `world`'s `font-size` will end up (1.5em x 1.2em x 1em) large.

While maintaining the same html structure, can we somehow make it just (1.5em x 1em) large?

```
<p style="font-size:1em;">
    <span style="font-size:1.2em"> Hello <span style="font-size:1.5em">world</span>. </span>
</p>
```

**UPDATE:**

In my case simply using `rem` units appears to be the best best. It's supported by IE 9+ (in addition to Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.6+, Opera 11.6+ and Safari 4.1+)

`rem` Represents the font-size of the root element (typically `<html>`). When used within the root element font-size, it represents its initial value (a common browser default is 16px, but user-defined preferences may modify this).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem

`:root` Selects the root element of the document: `<html>` in the case of HTML

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

```
/* css */
:root {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

html:

```
<span style="font-size:1.2rem">

    Hello <!-- this is 1.2em (relative to <html> root) -->

    <span style="font-size:1.5rem">world.</span> <!-- this is nested but still only 1.5em (relative to <html> root) -->

</span>
```

Also using em units alone this could have been worked out with the css `calc()` function (which is also supported by IE 9+) and some javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Thank you everyone for your answers and help with this!

Comment: no, em values are relative to the parent element, you will have to recalculate based on the current context.

Comment: with js maybe could you override what it thinks of as it's parent?

Comment: Do you need a value that several elements will be relative to?

Comment: I want children and grandchildren of P to be relative to P

Comment: @Morty Ok, see my answer using CSS variables.

Comment: You could use `rem` units to make it relative to the root element  font-size.

Comment: @KevinBoucher yeah I was going to add that as well then remembered CSS variables. CSS variables would be more appropriate since OP wants `<p>` as the referenced `font-size`

Comment: `rem` units are better supported than I thought. i'm not sure what qualifies the root element but I will look into this.

Comment: @Morty the root element is the top element in a document. In a document with HTML5, that would be `<html>` as a CSS selector it is: `html`. The special pseudo-class selector [:root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) is `<html>` *but* it will take a higher precedence than `html` because it's specify is higher.

Comment: @Morty see update with **Demo 2** using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `calc()` function can help:

```
<p style="font-size:1em;">
  <span style="font-size:1.2em"> Hello 
     <span style="font-size:calc(1.5em * (1/1.2))">world</span>. 
  </span>
</p>
```

```html
<code>What you have:</code>
<p style="font-size:1em;">
  <span style="font-size:1.2em"> Hello <span style="font-size:1.5em">world</span>. </span>
</p>

<hr>

<code>What you want, by using calc() function:</code>
<p style="font-size:1em;">
  <span style="font-size:1.2em"> Hello <span style="font-size:calc(1.5em * (1/1.2))">world</span>. </span>
</p>
```

### Explanation

Here's your code:

```
<p style="font-size:1em;">
    <span style="font-size:1.2em"> Hello <span style="font-size:1.5em">world</span>.</span>
</p>
```

Let's say the `body` element is set to 16px and is the parent of your `p` element.

Since `em` units are relative to the parent, this means that the `p` has a font size of 16px.

```
1em = 16px
```

As a result, the child of `p` – the first `span` – has a font size of 19.2px.

```
1.2em * 16px = 19.2px
```

The child of the `span` – another `span` – then has a font size of 28.8px.

```
1.5em * 19.2px = 28.8
```

You want your second `span` to be 24px, which is the font size of its grandparent (16px) times 1.5.

So this would be the calculation:

```
font-size: calc(1.5em * (1/1.2))

1em / 1.2em     = .833em
1.5em * .833em  = 1.25em
1.25em * 19.2px = 24px
```

Comment: That's really interesting and I didn't know about the css calc() function. It appears to be supported decently well too. I'm not sure if it will be more or less complex than the non-nested version of my project but this is a great answer.